# Смена картинки метки в objectManager по клику

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Стоит задача: сменить картинку по клику на конкретном `placeholder`. Метки генерятся из `json` аналогично приведенному в примерах.

```
function init() {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [57.8, 39],
    zoom: 7,
    controls: []
    });

    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
    clusterize: true,
    gridSize: 32,
    clusterDisableClickZoom: true
    });

    objectManager.objects.options.set({
    iconLayout: 'default#image',
    iconImageSize: [40, 40],
    iconImageOffset: [-20, -40]
    });    
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    $.ajax({
    url: "http://gastro.promeng.tk/jsonreply"
    }).done(function (data) {
    objectManager.add(data);
    });

    //Здесь пытаюсь изменить картинку у метки на которую кликаем

    objectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (e) {
    e.get('target').options.set({
        iconImageHref: '/map-pin-2.png'
    });

    });
}
```

Консоль молчит, ошибок не выдает, адрес картинки указан верно.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, исполняемый код примера. Сейчас непонятно, это листинг неполный или как раз ваша ошибка в том, что потерялся ymaps.ready(init).
Кроме того, если при создании OM не указать дефолтный url изображения, как у вас в коде, то метки не будут отображаться, потому что у них ещё нет картинки, которую отобразить в пресете.

Answer (score 1):

```
objectManager.objects.events.add('click', function (e) {
    objectManager.objects.setObjectOptions(e.get('objectId'),
    {iconImageHref: '/map-pin-2.png'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

разобрался

.options.set не работает с этими объектами, для них есть 
.setObjectOptions()